# Exception error when enabling workspace specific services in Geoserver 2.5 OpenGeo suite

Tags: geoserver, java, boundless-suite, osx

When I try and enable a workspace specific WMS in the bundled GeoServer app from boundless I get the following error.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

This is running on OSX 10.9.5 with java version

```
java version "1.6.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_65-b14-462-11M4609)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.65-b04-462, mixed mode)
```

The WMS works in global mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the version at http://geoserver.org and used that instead.

The Mac integration isn't quite as good but this version works.